# Google Maps v3 WebService API Straightline Distance

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I've been looking for Gmaps Web-service API to measure the distance between two points. it's been about 2 months and still no luck.
All solution I found was standard google maps distance calculation.

[image: Maps Distance]

What I wanted is the 9.32Km distance, not the 10.4Km (See the above picture)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of function in php:

```
echo calculateDistance(27.1010, 27.1020, 26.1010, 26.1020, "K");

function calculateDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

// Output: 149.15401829861 in KM
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So currently google doesn't have that kind of service.

I just tested it and the result is usable for the project.
calculateDistance(40.690569, -73.997659, 40.665436, -73.892219, "K")
Google Maps : 9.37 Km
Your Function : 9.31 Km

Comment: I think if you your custom function gives you perfect result then there is no need to hit API, whether it exist or not.

Comment: true, requires a lot of effort for the system to get the API result...
Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, there are so many factors like network etc. So best is to us your function, if possible. Happy coding :)